# Changing the default value for multiple fields in a list

Tags: 2013, list, default-value

Is there a way to set something simple up for an end user to be able to change the default value for multiple fields in a list?

I would ideally like to have a form to fill out, preferably like the default edit form. Having them go into the list settings and changing each field will not work.

If there's not an OOTB way that I'm missing and need to use REST or CSOM that is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Fields REST API. First you would get the fields, then you could enumerate through each to get the current default values. If the user changes the default value, you could use a HTTP MERGE request to update the DefaultValue property. This could all be done with HTML JavaScript. A nice addition would be to use the RoleAssignments/RoleDefinitionBindings on the list to first check if the user has permissions to manage the list, which would be required to update the default value. See the fields REST API reference here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn600182.aspx and the users/groups rest api here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn531432.aspx

Comment: I was able to grab the fields using REST but to post them back used JSOM so I could batch update the fields.